# Asperger's and math

Tags: soft-question, education

I am 19, recently diagnosed with Asperger's syndrome. Question to anyone here who has AS:

**Has your AS helped you or held you back while learning math? If so, in what ways?**

Comment: I don't know if AS is in any way helpful or a hindrance for mathematics; but this question is spectacularly off topic here. It's opinion based, it's particularly narrow, and I think it is better being asked at a forum aimed for people diagnosed with AS (which could give you similar experiences for physics, chemistry, or anything which might be related to studying in general).

Comment: Perhaps [talking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Phoenixia1177) with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Phoenixia1177) Wikipedia user might be of some help.

Comment: I supervised an independent study project for someone with high-level AS shortly before I retired. I cannot say whether he was at all typical, but I’d say that in his case it had both positive and negative effects: he could focus very intensely, but sometimes he’d focus on the wrong thing and get badly sidetracked for a while. I’d strongly recommend two things: talking to others in your situation, and getting expert advice on what to watch out for. My student had benefited greatly from the latter.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you a lot for your advice and kind words, sir.

Comment: @user132181: You're very welcome. Good luck!